# Can I reverse-proxy POST requests while using CloudFront CDN for GET requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Currently I have CloudFront distribution that serves SPA (`spa.myapp.com`) from S3 bucket. I have also web server deployed in k8s on AWS.

1. Is it possible to forward all POST spa.myapp.com/* requests to my web server instead? What components / configuration I need to do this?
2. Is it possible to forward all spa.myapp.com/api/* requests to my web server instead (regardless of http method)? What components / configuration I need to do this?

Generally I want to serve SPA from CDN but also have few endpoints server side on same domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On your CloudFront Behavior for `*` path you should allow all kind of methods:

[image]

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html):

> CloudFront always caches responses to `GET` and `HEAD` requests. You can also configure CloudFront to cache responses to OPTIONS requests. CloudFront does not cache responses to requests that use the other methods.

This means that `POST` requests are always redirected to the origin (back-end), responses to these requests wont be cached. `GET` and `HEAD` requests may also be redirected, if there is a cache miss. Otherwise, the data from the cache is returned.

2. When you crate a CloudFront distribution, you have to set up a behavior be default. Usually, you leave the default path pattern as it is, so `*`:

[image]

You can have multiple behaviors, which can have different properties for caching. These behaviors are differentiated by their path pattern. They can also have a priority, the incoming requests are evaluated against higher precedence behaviors first. For example:

[image]

To answer your question, what you have to do is to create a different behavior for the `/api/*` path and apply a different configuration for this behavior. This has to have a higher precedence compared to the default behavior. Keep in mind that CloudFront caches `GET`, `HEAD` and `OPTIONS` requests only.